# UICollectionView custom class not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new in iOS programming and I apologize for the lack of experience.

I have a storyboard with UITabViewController and 2 tabs ( call it First and Second as example ). On "First" tab ( custom class - CFirstTabController ) I placed Collection View with custom class - CCollectionViewController. In it I placed Collection View Cell, added custom class to it - all as need.

Here class CCollectionViewController:

```
#import "CCollectionViewController.h"
#import "CSomeClassAsDataSource.h"

@implementation CCollectionViewController

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        [self setDataSource:[CSomeClassAsDataSource init]];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)reloadData
{
    [super reloadData];
}

@end
```

And here is a problem: I want use other class as dataSource (CSomeClassAsDataSource implements protocol for it ), but I can't set it! Methods of this class not invoked. And I do not know why. I'm registered class CCollectionViewController as "Custom class" for my Controller View, but seems Xcode ignores it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataSource initialisation seems to be wrong as you've missed the `alloc`. Should be:

```
self.dataSource = [CSomeClassAsDataSource alloc] init];
```

Comment: I tried such point, but the problem in all method initWithFrame:... I set breakpoint on first line of them and I never reached it...

Comment: Implement the `- (void)awakeFromNib` method in your custom collectionview subclass, and see if the control arrives there.